# Positive sentence for "it won't take long"

Tags: phrase-request

How would you rephrase "it won't take long" to a positive sentence?
Is "it will take short" idiomatic?

More context: "it" refers to any activity like shopping, or hair cutting, or tidying up.

Comment: I wouldn't rephrase.  "It won't take long" is a perfectly acceptable sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the exact context, but something like "I'll be done shortly" or "It will be done soon" could work. You can't say "It will take short."

Comment: Thx. I added more context into my question.